# Как ускорить подключение по ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

Подключение уже после проверки пароли происходит очень медленно, около 5-20 секунд, ранее подключался к хосту за 1-2 секунды, что это может быть, куда копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UsePAM no, UseDNS no

Если директива UsePAM включена, то запустить sshd можно будет только от имени root.

UseDNS - пытается преобразовать ip-адрес подключающего клиента в обратное имя.195.208.238.155 - [155.238.208.195.IN-ADDR.ARPA](http://155.238.208.195.IN-ADDR.ARPA)Чаще всего, именно этот процесс делает паузу.

---

Добавил через 4 часа.

---

GSSAPIAuthentication no

---

Возникла ситуация, как у тебя сегодня.Помогло только отключение этой опции.http://alexm.here.ru/cvs-ru/html_node/cvs-ru_32.html - на русском о ней. Мало, непонятно.http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/sshGSSAPI.html - здесь больше. Англ не шарю.

Answer (score 1):

В конфиге 'sshd_config' отключите DNS и PAM, UsePAM no, UseDNS no, в ряде случаев помогает.

Comment: хотелось бы, конечно, более полный ответ (что делают эти опции?), но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

в /etc/pam.d/common-session закоментируй строку "session optional        pam_systemd.so"

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что это даст